# Nginx upd loadbalancing requests redirect to just to one server

Tags: nginx, udp, load-balancing

I have used following `nginx.conf` for my server, but it doesnt send `udp` requests to the balancing servers, always traffic goes to one server. If remove it, traffic goes to the second server.

My nginx.conf :

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;



stream {
        upstream radius_loadbalance {
#               least_conn;
                server 123.456.789.123:1813;
                server 123.456.789.124:1813;
                server 123.456.789.125:1813;
        }

        server {
                listen 1813 udp;
                proxy_pass radius_loadbalance;
                proxy_responses 1;
        }
}


events {
        worker_connections 768;
        multi_accept on;
}
```

Comment: Have you reloaded after commenting the least_conn; ? nginx -t && service nginx reload

Comment: @flaixman Yes. restarted using `systemctl restart nginx`